# How to listen for volume up/down key in android with nativescript?

Tags: android, nativescript

I just want to know how to access volume up and down key in native script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that in NativeScript you can use the code provided by James and extend the main activity for your Android NativeScript application. Below I am going to describe the steps needed to achieve that functionality with TypeScript project.

- Create new file in your `app` folder called `activity.android.ts`
- in the newly created file extend the Activity and overwrite `dispatchKeyEvent`
  as done [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/blob/master/others/extendedActivity/app/activity.android.ts) in my demonstration application
- lastly, [provide the new activity to your `AndroidManifest`](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/blob/master/others/extendedActivity/app/App_Resources/Android/AndroidManifest.xml#L28-L31) file by replacing the default one created by NativeScript
- build the application and use volume keys - the code will be triggered as expected ([in the demo application simple `console.log`](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/blob/master/others/extendedActivity/app/activity.android.ts#L53))

The whole demo application demonstrating the technique can be found [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/others/extendedActivity).
Article section on how to extend the Android Activity in NativeScript can be found [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity#extending-activity) (both TypeScript and vanilla JavaScript example).

Comment: I created a file called `activity.android.ts` and copy the complete code given in your demonstration application after that it's saying that can not find module **ui/frame**. What to do?

Comment: `ui/frame` is part of tns-core-modules. have you installed all the dependencies in your project (run `tns build android` or `npm install`)

Comment: you can directly clone and run the demo application and see if you have any missing part in the implementation

Comment: Yes, I already installed that. I can do 'require("ui/frame") in js file but in ts file it's showing that error.

Comment: Nick Iliev, could you suggest please, how to catch this event in application later?


application.android.on( <what should be here?>, function (args) {
    console.log("Event: " + args.eventName + ", Activity: " + args.activity);
});

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the *power button* thing you are trying to do, but to handle key press events, you can try overriding `dispatchKeyEvent`

In short you handle the event and process `KeyCode` and `Action` - something like this

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    // Which direction did the key move (up/down)
    int action = event.getAction();

    // What keywas pressed
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            // Check your event code (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP etc)
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                // Check your event code (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP etc)
            return true;
        default:
            // Let the system do what it wanted to do
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Here is the [full list](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) of `KeyEvent` options. hope this will get you going. There is a very short description about `despatchKeyEvent` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html#dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent))

Comment: I think this one is for android. I want to do this with native script.

Comment: @PavanVora - My apologies, i completely overlooked the _nativescript_ tag.