# Key bindings in nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am building android app using nativescript,
My apk will be installed on Android TV
How do I configure my nativescript app to be navigatable by remote/fly air mouse keys?

For example I have remote for my android tv like this one

[image]

I want to bind UI actions with UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT & OK keys
Also want app to take input by numeric keys 0 to 9,
just like we navigate to a channel on regular tv.

Comment: You will probably need a communication channel like Bluetooth ar WiFi via the remote API. Once you can access the remote API, you should be able to simply create a binding to the event listeners for the different buttons.

Comment: the remote does not have any API, I mean Android have built in API to handle directional keypress events, I am not sure how do I do this in nativescript https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation

Comment: In that case, I guess you could use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943511/how-to-listen-for-volume-up-down-key-in-android-with-nativescript where I am showing on how to apply custom logic for a specific key press from the keyboard (it looks like that air mouse is recognized a keyboard). I am extending the Android Activity to overwrite the default key events

Comment: Here is the key event dispatcher example https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2017/blob/master/others/extendedActivity/app/activity.android.ts#L43-L63

Comment: Of course, you will have to handle the different keys logic - here  you can find the list of key events https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent